# R: How to count the number of consecutive occurrences in a longitudinal database with a length condition?

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-cleaning, longitudinal, rle

I am working on R with a longitudinal database about individuals, with several rows per ID (named `vn` in the database) and their attributes in column. My variable `observation` indicates each year of observation and `maritalstatus` indicates whether the person is married `1` or not `0`.

Here is an overview of an individual in my database:

```
structure(list(vn = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), maritalstatus = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), observation = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018)), class = "data.frame")
```

I am looking for a way to create a new variable that counts the number of consecutive occurrences only the first time their length is greater or equal to 5. For this example it would be:

`marital_length = c (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`

My current code (below) creates a variable that counts the maximum length of consecutive numbers but I didn't find a way to add a condition to count only the first time the length is `>= 5`.

````
maritalstatus_consecutive <- tapply(test$maritalstatus, INDEX = test$vn, most_consecutive_val)```

test$marital_length <- maritalstatus_consecutive[test$vn]
````

I also tried to use `min()` (instead of max) but for instance if a person is married 2 years, divorced, then married 6 years and I won't be able to see in this new variable that she was married 6 years if I don't add the condition `>=5`.

Does anyone have an idea for a code that could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is too convulated but seems to work :

```
df$marital_length <- with(df, ave(maritalstatus, vn, FUN = function(x) 
                with(rle(x), rep(as.integer(seq_along(lengths) == 
                     which.max(lengths >= 5)) * lengths, lengths))))


df$marital_length
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

`which.max(lengths >= 5)` gives the index for first time when length is greater than 5.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your expected output is trying to represent. If you'd like just the length of the first marriage >=5 years for each `vn` you could use

```
tapply(df$maritalstatus, df$vn, function(x) with(rle(x), lengths[lengths >= 5][1]) )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When using your code, I receive the following error message (which I also received when I was trying to find a code that worked):                              `Erreur : Assigned data tapply(...) must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 21942461 rows.
x Assigned data has 2471783 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.`